# Specifying Visibilty in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using ListView but I want to replace listview by image when there is no item in my listview, is there anyway to perform such task in Android.

```
ll_result_trips = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ll_result_trips);   
        Iv_no_activity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Iv_no_activity);

if (data.size() > 0){
                                tv_no_of_result.setText(""+data.size() + " results found");
                               pAdapter adapter = new pAdapter(GhActivity.this,Data.data);
                                ll_result_trips.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                ll_result_trips.setAdapter(adapter);

                                Iv_no_activity.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                            }else {
                                tv_no_of_result.setText("No result found");
                                ll_result_trips.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Iv_no_activity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
```

XML

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_result_trips"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/nothing"
        android:id="@+id/Iv_no_activity"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are passing any list to listview

```
if(list.size==0){
 listView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
else {
 listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Comment: void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference - This is the error I get

Comment: please edit your question with code

Comment: Have you defined findviewbyid of imageview ?

Comment: yes @ Wahdat I have defined it

Comment: please show that line

Comment: added above in the code

Comment: It seems it doesn't find the view with the id you provide

Comment: please try to use id of view in small and check

Answer (score 0):

Put both an `ImageView` and a `ListView` in your xml and make both of them take up the whole space, set this property on the `ImageView`:

`android:visibility="gone"`

Then in the Java code when drawing the view, do something like:

```
if (listView.childCount() == 0) {
    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else {
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ImageView for instance in the same layout and toggle it's visibility depending on the list view state.